# How to access path of a RestController, using @Autowired/@Inject in another RestController in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

*This is an example done in J2EE application, I am looking for
an exact solution for this in Spring Boot.*

**path: localhost:8080/first/second/get-this**
Output: **Here You Go!**

```
//First Resource
@Path("first")
@RequestScoped
public class FirstResource {

@Inject
SecondResource secondResource;

@Path("second")
public SecondResource getSecondResource() {
    return secondResource;
    }
}

//Second Resource
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
public class SecondResource {

@Path("get-this")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getThisMessage(){
System.out.println("Here You Go!");    
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[Sub-resources](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) is a feature of JAX-RS, an API from JavaEE/JakartaEE. There is no sub-resources or any equivalent feature in Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux APIs.
What you could do is create the Rest controllers using [Jersey inside Spring](https://zetcode.com/springboot/jersey/), Jersey is the reference implementation for JAX-RS so it supports sub-resources.

Comment: Huh. This is the first time I've run across a JAX-RS feature that isn't in Spring but that I'd really like to have.

Comment: Thats true spring does not support it directly. Perhaps we can implement this with the help of `Autowiring`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57311688/3308908